# Pattern Lock Ionic 2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

Currently, I am implementing a mobile application using Ionic 2, Angular 2 anf Firebase for my school assignment. I've been searching all over Google for the pattern lock but I couldn't find anything.
I need helps from you guys. Really appreciate it :)
Below is my idea:

1. Create a matrix of 3 x 3
2. Give them a listener (ondragstart and ondragend)<= my assumption
3. Keep track on position that have been dragged (for example, if the user drag from position 1 to 2 to 3 to 6 to 9)
4. Save the number in my firebase
5. when the user login, if he/she drag the same pattern, they will login

[**I want to have something like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0JLu.png)

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use this jQuery library [patternlock](https://github.com/s-yadav/patternLock/blob/master/README.md)

Use this sample code 
      `var lock = new PatternLock("#patternContainer");`

Comment: I've found this solution too but is it possible to import this jQuery into ionic 2?

Comment: absolutely possible in two ways . import in index.html <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: then use by this diclaration  declare var $: any;

Comment: otherwise install jquery from npm and import inside to use

Comment: omg after trying multiple times, I was managed to run it. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: great , welcome @serenex :)